# What is Shesh Mashzar?

Tags: hebrew, exodus, historical-interpretation

The Hebrew words occuring all over the latter parts of Exodus:

שֵׁשׁ מָשְׁזָר

mean some sort of fancy fabric. Is it reasonable to think of this as silk? I was thinking this might be derived from "six" (shesh) for a while, but now I think it is probably an onomatopoiea, meaning a cloth that makes the sound "shesh-shesh" when it rubs against itself. This might be any finely woven cloth, like silk or satin, but I don't know how old these materials are.

I should add that "Mash-zar" is something like "strange-feel", so this is a "strange-feeling shesh-shesh cloth" or else a sixfold cloth of strange-feel. I translated it (wrong, wrong, wrong) as "sixfold wrought cloth" which I then suspected, but I am now sure, is totally wrong, as it implies an extremely coarse fabric, where the other interpretation is as a fine fabric.

What is this stuff? Is there consensus? Could it be silk?

Comment: I am aware that "silk" is not the best interpretation considering that it is used for drapes, but perhaps a finely woven canvas? I just want an idea of what this could be.

Comment: Silk is extremely old; they have been making it in China for thousands of years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Definitions

**שֵׁשׁ** (*shesh*; Strong's [8336](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H8336&t=KJV)) comes from **שַׁיִשׁ** (*shayish*; Strong's [7893](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/Lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H7893&t=KJV)), meaning to *bleach* or *whiten*. Thus *shesh* can indicate white/bleached clothe ([byssus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/byssus)/[linen](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Handkerchief.jpg)), or white stone ([alabaster](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Alabaster.jpg)/[marble](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8d/MarbleUSGOV.jpg)). **מָשְׁזָר** (*mashzar*) is hophal of **שָׁזַר** (*shazar*; Strong's [7806](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H7806&t=KJV)) and means *twisted*:

[image: Gesenius on *shazar*]

#### Translation Examples

*Shesh* occurs alone in Exodus [28:5](http://interlinearbible.org/exodus/28-5.htm):

> Have them use gold, and blue, purple and scarlet yarn, and **fine linen**. (NIV)
>
> So give them **fine linen cloth**, gold thread, and blue, purple, and scarlet thread. (NLT)
>
> And they shall take gold, and blue, and purple, and scarlet, and **fine linen**. (KJV)

*Mashzar* occurs alone in [39:24](http://interlinearbible.org/exodus/39-24.htm):

> They made pomegranates of blue, purple and scarlet yarn and **finely twisted linen** around the hem of the robe. (NIV)
>
> They made pomegranates of blue, purple, and scarlet **yarn**, and attached them to the hem of the robe. (NLV)
>
> And they made upon the hems of the robe pomegranates of blue, and purple, and scarlet, and **twined linen**. (KJV)

They occur together in [39:2](http://interlinearbible.org/exodus/39-2.htm):

> They made the ephod of gold, and of blue, purple and scarlet yarn, and of **finely twisted linen**. (NIV)
>
> Bezalel made the ephod of **finely woven linen** and embroidered it with gold and with blue, purple, and scarlet thread. (NLT)
>
> And he made the ephod of gold, blue, and purple, and scarlet, and **fine twined linen**. (KJV)

The NLT scores on precision in the translation of these terms!

#### Summary

The consensus seems to be that *shesh mashzar* is *fine woven/twisted linen/byssus*; I prefer *fine woven linen* (NLT) after my investigation. It is almost certainly not [silk](http://topicalbible.org/s/silk.htm).

Comment: @JonEricson You may notice how keen I am on picking up your bounties... ;)

Comment: I'll keep offering them if you keep [picking them up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129212/1438)!  (In [5-ish hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78942/1438), I'll award it.  I'm not sure this answer completely answers Ron's question, but it's good enough for me.)

Comment: @JonEricson Thanks. I sometimes forget to reread the question after answering...edited a bit to answer more directly.

Comment: Fantastic, +1 and accepted, and I am impressed at the persuasive research. I knew the accepted translations, but I couldn't find the roots corresponding, and this does it.